# Live Sass Compiler is not **Automatically** update

Tags: css, sass

I'm using [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) in VScode but it **does conflict with Live Server**, preventing the auto-refreshing mode, even it's showing ***Watching*** in the output tab.
And when I turn ***Watch SASS*** button off the **Live Server** works fine.

I tried it on FireFox & Chrome | OS: Windows 10

Do Any One Faced The Same Issue Before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here in this [comment](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/452#issuecomment-490996875)

> My folder Name was starting with (hash) `#folderName`